# Java overriding parent equals method

Tags: java

I have two classes `Person` and `Teacher`. In the `Person` class I check if the two objects passed in are equal using the compareTo method. In the `Teacher` class, the problem I'm working on states that I need to override the `equals` method in Person. In this `equals` method, the only way it would return true is if it's equal in both the `equals` method in `Person` and `Teacher`. My question is, when I check in the `Teacher`'s `equals` method, do I just call `super.equals(other)` in order to check if the two objects are equal by the parent class or is there something else I need to do?

Person:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {


    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        try {
            return this.compareTo(other) == 0;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Teacher

```
public class Teacher extends Person {
    private String facultyID;
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        boolean personEquals = super.equals(other);
        try {
            Teacher teach1 = (Teacher)other;
            boolean idEquals = this.facultyID.equals(teach1.facultyID);
            if(idEquals && personEquals)
                return true;
            return false;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.compareTo(other)` does not return a `boolean`. That should read `this.compareTo(other) == 0`.

Comment: Be very wary about having two competing implementations of `equals`. That way leads to non-symmetric equality.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu Thanks for the catch! I edited the code to change that.

Comment: @khelwood I'm studying for my CS final and one of the problems asked me to write an equals method to override the one in the parent class. But, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Andrew What khelwood is saying refers to the [`Object.equals(Object)` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) which specifies in part that *It is **symmetric**: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the contract of [`Object#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) states:

> It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true

And the implementation of `Teacher#equals` doesn't meet this requirement. For cases when implementing `equals` method in a class that inherits from another that is not `Object` e.g. `Teacher`, you should verify if the type of the object to be compared is **the same as** the class you're comparing. To achieve this, you should use `getClass().equals`:

```
public class Teacher extends Person {
    private String facultyID;
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        //this line is nonsense, not all Persons are Teachers
        //boolean personEquals = super.equals(other);

        //avoid using try-catch
        //try {

        //verify that the other object is not null
        if (other == null) {
            return false;
        }

        //verify that the other object is specifically a Teacher, not a super or a subclass of it
        if (this.getClass().equals(other.getClass()) {
            //here comes the real check
            Teacher otherTeacher = (Teacher)other;
            return this.facultyID.equals(otherTeacher.facultyID);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Do similar for `Person` in case it should not allow comparing against subclasses of it.